# How should I fix "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function."?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-5

I'm using `typescript` and `eslint`. Eslint complaing about return after `=>` arrow, when I added it this didn't work either - `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => return {}`. What is the correct syntax for -

```
function getSizeFromObjectUrl(dataURL: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                const ratio = Math.min(300.0 / img.width, 300.0 / img.height);
                return resolve({
                    height: img.height * ratio,
                    width: img.width * ratio
                });
            };
            img.src = dataURL;
        } catch (exception) {
            return reject(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

using it like -

`const size = await getSizeFromObjectUrl(imageUrl);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is about consistent return: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return

> A confusing aspect of JavaScript is that a function returns undefined if any of the following are true:

> - it does not execute a return statement before it exits
> - it executes return which does not specify a value explicitly
> - it executes return undefined
> - it executes return void followed by an expression (for example, a function call)
> - it executes return followed by any other expression which evaluates to undefined

> If any code paths in a function return a value explicitly but some code path do not return a value explicitly, it might be a typing mistake, especially in a large function.

So what you need you can do to get rid of the message is:

- explicitly return something in the `try` block (`return undefined` if you will)
- stop returning in the `catch` block
- disable the rule for that function

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is:

```
function getSizeFromObjectUrl(dataURL: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                const ratio = Math.min(300.0 / img.width, 300.0 / img.height);
                resolve({
                    height: img.height * ratio,
                    width: img.width * ratio
                });
            };
            img.src = dataURL;
        } catch (exception) {
            reject(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

it's actually complaining about the return before resolve / reject not after the arrow. cuz the resolve and reject functions are voids

for the error `Unexpected lexical declaration in case block.`, use the case like this :

```
case x: {
    // your code goes here
}
```

instead of:

```
case x: 
    // your code
```

Comment: eslint is complaining about return after arrow.

Comment: cause you cant add a return after an arrow, the arrow already working as a return.

Comment: in the answer above there is no return after any arrow

Comment: it is expecting a return after => with current code. I found that removing return before promise resolve/rejects makes eslint happy.

Comment: yeah i got you know, i updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I removed return before promise resolve/reject. This works -

```
function getSizeFromObjectUrl(dataURL: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const img = new Image();
            img.onload = () => {
                const ratio = Math.min(300.0 / img.width, 300.0 / img.height);
                resolve({
                    height: img.height * ratio,
                    width: img.width * ratio
                });
            };
            img.src = dataURL;
        } catch (exception) {
            reject(exception);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Although I like this answer because it resolves your issue I think @aquele-hugo's is better because it explains why there is an issue.